# Can anybody help me with sample codes to execute mysql stored procedure for RestFul web services

Tags: mysql, spring, web-services, rest

I'm new to programming, & have to create an web service url that will execute an MySql stored procedure, can anybody help me for sending input parameters & getting output parameters through spring web service code,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

i went through various sites & articled & found some links that might be helpfull for all

http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2014/08/spring-restful-web-services.html

http://www.concretepage.com/spring/how-to-call-stored-procedure-in-spring-jdbc

Comment: If anybody found more links that are more easy to implement business logic & validation, please share those links